# Rows mismatch error in Python regression FOR loop

Tags: python

I am looking to build a FOR loop program in Python to iteratively run hundreds of OLS regressions. I have a data frame containing 24 observations and 701 variables. ‘Y’ is the dependent variable and all other are independent variables (X1 to X700).

My objective is to run 700 simple regressions – by regressing Y on each X.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv(r'file_location\regression_data.csv') # input dataset that contain 701 variables and 24 observations

list_iv   #  this list contains names of all the 700 independent variables (X1 to X700). Read from a .csv file
list_dsn  # this contains list of strings (v1, v2, v3…..v700). Read from a .csv file

gbl = globals()
for i, k in zip(list_iv, list_dsn):
    gbl['output_'+k] = sm.ols('Y ~ i',data=df).fit()
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
raise PatsyError(msg, origin)
PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and i (24 versus 1)
    DR ~ i
         ^
```

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Please note - in each iteration I will create a dataframe that contain regression coefficients, p-values and standard errors using output_k.params, output_k.pvalues and output_k.bse, respectively. All these 700 dataframes will be concatenated to create final dataframe that will contain 700 observations.

Comment: Can you print shape of list_iv and list_dsn?

Comment: @Sheece Gardazi, both list_dsn and list_iv have the following shape: (5,)

Comment: You have DataFrame not lists here. Transform DataFrame to list first. Try to find the length by using `len(list_iv)` and `len(list_dsn)`.  Do that before your for loop. You must have a problem with the size of your lists.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu both  `list_iv` & `list_dsn` were created from a dataframe using `list_iv = df2["ivs"].tolist()` & `list_dsn = df2["dsn"].tolist()` functions. Length of both the lists are 700. Dataframe `df2` itself was created by reading in a .csv file

Comment: I usually get this sort of error when variables are of different dimensions. Can you share minimal data so I can try to reproduce this error ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share the line which gives the error you mention. I have a doubt that the error is related to the for loop.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu below is the line where I am getting the error:
  `File "C:\Users\navi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py", line 795, in check
    raise PatsyError(msg, origin)

PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and i (24 versus 1)
    DR ~ i
            ^ `

Comment: @@SheeceGardazi following random data will generate the exact error i am getting: `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(24, 6)), 
                  columns = ['DR', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'])

list_iv    = ['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5']
list_dsn = ['v1','v2','v3','v4','v5']

gbl = globals()
for i, k in zip(list_iv, list_dsn):
    gbl['output_'+k] = sm.ols('DR ~ i', data = df).fit()`

Comment: I meant the line in your code that gives the error! Can you post it ? You do not need to Copy/Paste the error you have already mentioned in your question. Just add to your question the code which give the error, and point out the corresponding line.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu - i believe i am missing something in FOR loop. You will get exactly same error I am getting if you run the following code. Code generates a dummy dataframe.   `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(24, 6)), 
                  columns=['DR', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'])

list_dsn = ['v1','v2','v3','v4','v5']
list_iv = ['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5']

gbl = globals()
for i, k in zip(list_iv, list_dsn):
    gbl['output_'+k] = sm.ols('DR ~ i',data=df).fit()` thanks.

Comment: What Python version do you use ? I tested your code in Python 3 and it works.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu i am using Python 3.7.3 version in Anaconda3 2019.03. Can you please let me know exact version you are using, I will try to install the same? thanks.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 on Linux (Ubuntu), I do not use Anaconda.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu  I will instal another version of Anaconda and try my luck. many thanks for your inputs.